# No Module named ESPN_Scraper.items

Tags: python-2.7

I am learning python and am trying to run the code on this github project.

https://github.com/rcfbanalysis/rcfbscraper

When I try to run a command such as the following

```
python "C:\Python\rcfbscraper-master\ESPN_Scraper\ESPN_Scraper\spiders\espnSpider.py"
```

I get the error No Module named ESPN_Scraper.items. 
This is the offending line

```
from ESPN_Scraper.items import GameItem
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell is ESPN_Scraper items.py is not in your sys path. one quick work around for this would be to put the ESPN_Scraper directory in the same directory as your espnspider.py file.

Take a look at the docs https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html section 6.1.2

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you clarify what you mean by putting the espn_scraper directory in the same directory as the espnspider.py file? This is the path to the espnspider.py file. rcfbscraper-master\ESPN_Scraper\ESPN_Scraper\spiders. This is contained in the spiders directory which is in the ESPN_Scraper directory.

Comment: you may need to create another ESPN_Scrapers directory inside of the spiders directory and move the required files into the new directory... 
take  a look at the link I provided and see how python looks for dependencies, python looks in current directory, then sys path... it does not look backwards from current directory

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't get it to work with the ESPN_Scraper in front, I just removed that and moved the items file and I no longer got the error. My next step is figuring out how to return data. Thanks